# COMO IMPRIMIR MATRIZ DE DOS DIMENSIONES CON NOMBRES EN JAVA (STRING)

Tags: java, matrices

No sé que tengo mal en mi código, deseo imprimir una matriz 3x4 con nombres ya establecidos.

Quiero que el programa imprima los nombres sin tener que ingresarlos por consola.

Aquí dejo mi código:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

int iniciar;

System.out.println("Si desea iniciar presione 1.");
iniciar = sc.nextInt();

String matriz [][] = new String [3][4]; 

matriz [0][0] = "Juan";
matriz [0][1] = "Pedro";
matriz [0][2] = "Maria";

matriz [1][0] = "Josefa";
matriz [1][1] = "Manuel";
matriz [1][2] = "Julio";

matriz [2][0] = "Hector";
matriz [2][1] = "Miguel";
matriz [2][2] = "Jorge";

matriz [3][0] = "Francis";
matriz [3][1] = "Daniel";
matriz [3][2] = "David";


if (iniciar==1){
  
   for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < matriz.length; j++) {

            System.out.print(matriz[i][j].toString());
            
            System.out.print("\t");
        }

    }
}

System.out.print("\n");

}
```

Comment: que te está devolviendo el código actual?

Answer (score 1):

En primer lugar el arreglo que usas según se ve es de `4,3` y no de `3,4` como lo muestras en el código, lo siguiente es el for, puesto que ambos no tienen la misma longitud, deberías tener que hacer uso del `length` en la posición de `i`, solucionando eso, quedaría de la siguiente manera.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
  public static void main (String[]args)
  {
    String matriz[][] = new String[4][3];

      matriz[0][0] = "Juan";
      matriz[0][1] = "Pedro";
      matriz[0][2] = "Maria";

      matriz[1][0] = "Josefa";
      matriz[1][1] = "Manuel";
      matriz[1][2] = "Julio";

      matriz[2][0] = "Hector";
      matriz[2][1] = "Miguel";
      matriz[2][2] = "Jorge";

      matriz[3][0] = "Francis";
      matriz[3][1] = "Daniel";
      matriz[3][2] = "David";
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

    int iniciar;

    System.out.println ("Si desea iniciar presione 1.");
    iniciar = sc.nextInt ();


    if (iniciar == 1){
        for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < matriz[i].length; j++){
                System.out.print (matriz[i][j].toString ());
                System.out.print ("\t");
            }
            System.out.print ("\n");
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: y si quiero imprimirlo en forma 4x3?

Comment: Pues lo mas recomendable es transponer tu matriz.

Answer (score 1):

### Tu matriz

| [x],[y] | Columna 0 | Columna 1 | Columna 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Fila 0** | Juan | Pedro | Maria |
| **Fila 1** | Josefa | Manuel | Julio |
| **Fila 2** | Hector | Miguel | Jorge |
| **Fila 3** | Francis | Daniel | David |

### **Error n°1**

La matriz que creaste tiene 3 filas y 4 columnas.

```
String matriz [][] = new String [i][j];
```

Debería ser al revés. Es decir:

```
String matriz [][] = new String [4][3];
```

---

### **Error n°2**:

Explicado de una forma muy sintética (recomiendo reforzar con teoría de arreglos y matrices), una matriz es un arreglo de arreglos. El arreglo "principal" es el de las filas, y los arreglos "internos" son las columnas. En tu primer `for`, estás comparando el índice `i` con `matriz.length`, lo cual te devuelve la longitud del arreglo principal, el llamado "principal". Hasta ahí vas bien. Pero si te fijas, **estás comparando dos veces con exactamente el mismo valor**.

```
for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matriz[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(matriz[i][j].toString());
            System.out.print("\t");
        }
    }
}
```

Con esas dos modificaciones tu código debería funcionar bien.

Para que te sea más comprensible tu código, podrías trabajar con dos variables y hacerlo de esta forma:

```
int filas = 4, columnas = 3;

String matriz[][] = new String[filas][columnas];

matriz[0][0] = "Juan";
matriz[0][1] = "Pedro";
matriz[0][2] = "Maria";

matriz[1][0] = "Josefa";
matriz[1][1] = "Manuel";
matriz[1][2] = "Julio";

matriz[2][0] = "Hector";
matriz[2][1] = "Miguel";
matriz[2][2] = "Jorge";

matriz[3][0] = "Francis";
matriz[3][1] = "Daniel";
matriz[3][2] = "David";

if (iniciar == 1) {
    for (int i = 0; i < filas; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columnas; j++) {
            System.out.print(matriz[i][j].toString());
            System.out.print("\t");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: me sale todo en una fila, que hacer para imprimirlo 4x3

Comment: @UvilleraMente Por favor, explica mejor el problema. La matriz que tienes es 4x3 y necesitas imprimirla en 4x3, verdad? Porque en tu pregunta sigue diciendo 3x4 y se presta a confusiones.